# Magento2 customer emails for sales being received but not admin

Tags: magento2, email, order-email

Magento2 customer emails for sales being received but not the admin. Using Magento version 2.1.9

The customer receipt for order, shipping, credit emails are being received, but not admin.

I have already added in an email for each in the bcc area, but email not coming out. I have also changed the receiving email address to different mailboxes from different domains but makes no difference.

We have 2 other Magento2 installs on the same server with same settings that are working fine. 
Cron is enabled on all 3 domains and working. Any ideas on how to debug and fix?

Comment: Have you checked spam folder and add Gmail I'd into cc and check is that getting email or not. Look forward reply

Comment: Yes, already checked that, not the issue, the admin emails are not sending

Answer (score 2):

I would look if the emails are being sent. To do so, look on your email logs. If you use an SMTP server, it is likely that the provider also have a log over sent emails (charging is based upon sent quantity).

How to locate the log files? https://serverfault.com/questions/59602/where-to-check-log-of-sendmail

Please, below is a quote of above linke. I'm not sure what the best practices are here.

**Where are the logs?**

The default location depends on your linux/unix system, but the most common places are

1. /var/log/maillog
2. /var/log/mail.log
3. /var/adm/maillog
4. /var/adm/syslog/mail.log

If it's not there, look up `/etc/syslog.conf`. You should see something like this

```
mail.*         -/var/log/maillog
```

sendmail writes logs to the mail facility of syslog. Therefore, which file it gets written to depends on how syslog was configured.

If you system uses syslog-ng (instead of the more "traditional" syslog), then you'll have to look up your `syslog-ng.conf` file. You'll should something like this:

```
# This files are the log come from the mail subsystem.
#
destination mail     { file("/var/log/mail.log"); };
destination maillog  { file("/var/log/maillog"); };
destination mailinfo { file("/var/log/mail.info"); };
destination mailwarn { file("/var/log/mail.warn"); };
destination mailerr  { file("/var/log/mail.err"); };
```

End of quote.

If you could specify a bit more about your setup (how do you send your emails windows, linux?), and also what type of emails are being sent as admin (and that you miss), it would help.

The other area I would look in, is the email address itself. I have read the email server may refuse to send emails based on email addresses that aren't valid. If you could share it, would be appreciated as well as where in Magento Admin it is entered.

Then, I assume you have checked the spam folder. If you haven't specified your DNS records appropriately, your email is likely to be classified as spam. I've used this service to check before: http://www.mail-tester.com/ (don't know if it is good practice or not, but it gives some guidance).

Last point, check cron tab. I could imagine that the customer emails are one task, while admin is another task. Just a guess.

Comment: I don't think a lot of your answer is relevant to our problem. We know emails from the Magento install are firing properly, as the sales/shipment/credit emails etc are going to customer. It's the admin version of these emails that are not being received. Please see point in my question about other Magento2 installs on same server, with same setup, working fine. The likely cause of problem is missed setting in Magento admin somewhere. But what that is I can't see. Or plugin conflict possibly.

Comment: "Or plugin conflict possibly" - Just being a rubber duck here, but perhaps try disabling modules to eliminated this possibility?

Comment: So, you have checked your email log? Are emails being sent to the receivers indicated? It would help a lot to know, to support you better. In the question, it is stated "emails not being received". When you say admin version, it is the BCC or CC of e.g. a shipment or other transactional email?

Comment: It's any admin email, including the BCC version. When a Magento2 order is placed, it should send an order copy to the registered email in Magento system settings. It's this email that is not firing. The customer versions of these emails are coming out fine.

Comment: What does your email log say? It would help a lot!

Comment: The emails are showing in the email logs. They are not getting through to any email though. The contact form admin email works fine. I.e. it is send from the mailbox on domain. But the admin emails sent from this same mailbox for sales orders, shipments etc, the admin Magento version of these emails are not coming through. You can see them fine in the mail log like I say though.

Comment: Having tested this in the mail log and fired emails for other Magento2 installs on the same version of Magento that are working fine with same version of php and all settings the same, the other previous installs are working fine, and they show the same in the mail log. All of the Magento2 relevant settings to email are the same. Only difference is theme used. But changing to Magento default Luma theme, the issue still occurs.

Comment: As the emails are being indicated as sent by the mail server, my conclusion is that Magento is not to blame (it is sending the emails to the indicated address). 

The two following questions could be seen a bit rude but that is not at all my intention (I base those on weeks debugging Magento installations): 1) Have you checked the spam-folder? 2) The to (or bcc) email address in the logs are the same as the one you are checking? For 1) I see you confirmed above. 

What is the email setup you are using?

Comment: We have found the issue, and it's not Magento or server but was Office365..... the issue though I'm not 100% sure of. But essentially the mailbox could not email itself. So the mails weren't routing properly. But no bounce-back or error was received. So hard to debug. Not sure if this question should stay in place on that basis.... maybe parts of it will help others?

Comment: Well. For me, it is a good example of how not to debug and ask for help. There are two actions (among some others) in the initial answer I provided above 1) look in your log and 2) share a bit about your email setup. It took you long time to look in the log, but once done, it was clear the issue was not Magento. Your email setup is not clear for me still. 

For future reference, it would be good you clarify your email setup (from/to, SMTP, other) and the issue with Office365.